# Transferred code to new computer and catkin_make not working

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently transferred all of my ROS files to a new computer using a flash drive. Afterward, I installed ROS on the new computer but didn't go through any of the tutorials. I ran catkin_make in catkin_ws, but I keep getting the error that the configuration file or module for many of my packages cannot be found. I think this is happening because some packages are being built before their dependencies, but I'm not sure. Is there a better way to transfer code from computer to computer or is there any way to fix this? I'm pretty sure all of these packages have dependency files.

An example of the errors I'm getting contains the text:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
grasp_planner/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package moveit_ros_planning.

Set moveit_ros_planning_DIR to the directory containing a CMake
configuration file for moveit_ros_planning.  The file will have one of the
following names:

```
moveit_ros_planningConfig.cmake
moveit_ros_planning-config.cmake
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145881/transferred-code-to-new-computer-and-catkin_make-not-working./) by [schmellow](https://answers.ros.org/users/14001/schmellow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you delete the `build` and `devel` directories? In particular files created by cmake in `build` contains absolute paths, which will likely have changed after copying the code.

What do you mean by "but didn't go through any of the terminals" ?

**Edit**:

For best results it is probably good to also remove `install`. And then, to install all dependencies, inside your workspace, use rosdep again properly `rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y` (notice the "hydro").

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schmellow](https://answers.ros.org/users/14001/schmellow/) on 2014-03-31**:
sorry, i meant "tutorials". the post has been edited.

**Comment by [schmellow](https://answers.ros.org/users/14001/schmellow/) on 2014-03-31**:
i didn't delete those directories. is there any way to quickly fix any relative addressing?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-31**:
You should delete the `build` and `devel` directories and run catkin_make to build your workspace on your new system.

**Comment by [schmellow](https://answers.ros.org/users/14001/schmellow/) on 2014-03-31**:
i've done that and now i'm still getting errors similar to the one above. i tried to install dependencies using
"rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y"
but i'm getting errors similar to "
Multiple packages found with the same name "rosserial_client":

- install/share/rosserial_client
- src/rosserial/rosserial_client
  "

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-31**:
I would also remove the install directory.

**Comment by [schmellow](https://answers.ros.org/users/14001/schmellow/) on 2014-03-31**:
removed install, build, and devel, but still getting the same errors with catkin_make

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-31**:
Are you sure all of your dependencies are installed? Have you tried to install your dependencies now that you've removed the install folder that was causing your rosdep error?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-31**:
Removing install is probably a good idea. However getting the rosdep error is strange if you used the command you posted. With the `--from-paths ./src` option it should not have looked in `./install`. Nevermind... execute it again as @ahendrix suggests.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-31**:
Oh I just noticed you have installed hydro (according to the error message in your post), but the rosdep command specifies groovy. Make sure to use the distro you want for both the underlay and the rosdep command.

**Comment by [schmellow](https://answers.ros.org/users/14001/schmellow/) on 2014-04-17**:
I'm still getting the error "Cannot locate rosdep definition for [pcl]" when I use rosdep. Any other solutions?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-17**:
It seems that is some old package that is not meant for hydro. The rosdep key should probably be `libpcl-all-dev` not `pcl`. Maybe replace it in the package.xml. In any case, you can add `--ignore-keys pcl` to make rosdep ignore that dependency temporarily.

**Comment by [schmellow](https://answers.ros.org/users/14001/schmellow/) on 2014-04-17**:
i'm getting the error that --ignore-keys is not an option

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-17**:
Is it `--skip-keys`?

**Comment by [schmellow](https://answers.ros.org/users/14001/schmellow/) on 2014-04-17**:
it worked! how do i change my pcl files to work on hydro now, though?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-17**:
my bad, its --skip-keys as William pointed out. Which of your packages specifies the pcl dependency in its package.XML?